# Fastify prehandler (middleware) are running in concurrency with handler when use await

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm using Fastify (with typescript) and I want to make a middleware with validation in async flow before call the handler

I implemented a hook called `validateUser` and if I throw some error after any await function, the controller handler start before the responde of my preHandler.

I made this:

```
# My prehandler
export const validateUser = async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  const { data } = req.body as BodyData;
  const isValid = await MyApi.getCustomerIsValid(data);

  if (!isValid) {
    throw new BadRequestException('My custome message here'); // I implemented this Exception
  }
};
```

This does not work. If user is invalid the error isn't throw as expected.

If I change the code to check if my exception work, like this

```
# My prehandler
export const validateUser = async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  throw new BadRequestException('My custome message here'); // I put in the first line just to test
  const { data } = req.body as BodyData;
  const isValid = await MyApi.getCustomerIsValid(data);
  // ....
};
```

I can see the error.
I was invetigating here and I put some logs in my console in prehandler and in my controller. Like this

```
# My prehandler
export const validateUser = async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  console.log('validateUser - Start prehandler');
  const { data } = req.body as BodyData;
  const isValid = await MyApi.getCustomerIsValid(data);
  console.log('validateUser - After await');

  if (!isValid) {
    throw new BadRequestException('My custome message here'); // I implemented this Exception
  }
};
```

And in my handler, I put this

```
async myHandler(request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) {
    console.log('START REQUEST IN CONTROLLER');
    // .....
```

And my console log print in this order:

```
validateUser - Start prehandler
START REQUEST IN CONTROLLER
validateUser - After await
```

I believe that the preHandler is not awaiting to finish the request to start the controller handler :/

How can I solve this?

I'm using the version 4.7.0

Thanks for this

Comment: It seems correct - could you add some code that run and the TS config? Did you check the compiled code?

Comment: In my tsconfig I was using ES2016 and I changed to ES2020, but didn't work too :(